# Ensuring a an object type

Tags: java, instanceof

Everybody knows that before doing any cast we have to check the object type with `instanceof`, however, with generics the compiler doesn't allow us to check it with generics like this.

```
if(object instanceof List<Message>)
```

I was investigating its solution and some people say that we have to check with `List` only, however, this is not valid for me.
I also checked that some developers recommend using `isAssignableFrom`, but it requires `object` to have an instance.
So how can I check that object is a `List` of `Message` (and not a just a list) without creating a trick object?

Comment: You don't *have* to use `instanceof` in order to cast. In fact if you're doing a lot of unknown casts, you most likely have a design flaw that you should fix.

Comment: You should use [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) when working with generics. This, of course, only works if all elements in the list satisfy the condition/constraint.

Answer (score 0):

A bit naive approach

```
 Object deserializedList = fetchList();
 if (deserializedList instanceof List) {
   for (Object obj : (List)deserializedList) {
     if (obj instanceof Message) {
       Message message = (Message)obj;
       System.out.println("message: " + message);
     } else {
       System.out.println("not a message: " + obj);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: What if the list is empty?

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad then the `foreach`-loop is not entered. You may want to check that the `List` is not `null`: `if ((deserializedList != null) && (deserializedList instanceof List)) {`

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I don't want to do it. I might need to add something to the list afterwards.

Comment: "*That's exactly my problem. I don't want to do it.*" - you do not want to do what? "*I might need to add something to the list afterwards.*" - To the original list? There is nothing stopping you form doing that. Please give us a clear problem statement.

Comment: IF the list is empty, and I add one message, but it might be a list of something else.